# MySQL - JAVA Store procedure is gone in sometime

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, tomcat7, database-connection

I have a problem with MySQL and JAVA web application. I have created store procedure sp_doWriteLogTrans in mysql and it's work very well with my tomcat.

However when tomcat server stay idle for a while (No any requests) (1 Day) and after that I make a new request

to JAVA web application it always show error like this.

```
Jan 28, 2016 9:24:09 AM com.sun.xml.ws.server.sei.TieHandler createResponse
SEVERE: FUNCTION sp_doWriteLogTrans does not exist
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: FUNCTION sp_doWriteLogTrans does not exist
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
```

I don't know why this exception happen. But when I restart tomcat. It comes back to work very well again.

Here is my java code for communication with mysql

```
MySQLDB mydb = new MySQLDB();
        mydb.connect();
        String sql = "{call sp_doWriteLogTrans(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)}";
        CallableStatement call  = mydb.conn.prepareCall(sql);
        call.setString(1, type);
        call.setString(2, value1);
        call.setString(3, value2);
        call.setString(4, value3);
        call.setString(5, value4);
        call.setString(6, value5);
        call.setString(7, value6);
        call.setString(8, value7);
        call.setString(9, value8);
        call.setString(10, value9);
        call.setString(11, value10);
        call.setString(12, value11);
        call.setString(13, value12);
        call.setString(14, value13);
        call.setString(15, value14);
        call.setString(16, value15);
        call.setString(17, value16);
        call.setString(18, value17);
        call.setString(19, logno_ref);
        call.setString(20, command);
        call.registerOutParameter(21, Types.INTEGER);
        call.execute();
        String logno = call.getString(21);

        mydb.disconnect();
```

And this is connect method for MySQLDB class

```
public boolean connect() {


             // Get a context for the JNDI look up
            Context ctx;
            try {
                ctx = new InitialContext();
                Context envContext = (Context) ctx.lookup("java:/comp/env");
                javax.sql.DataSource ds = (javax.sql.DataSource) envContext.lookup ("jdbc/mysql"); 

                conn = ds.getConnection();
            } catch (NamingException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return true;

        }
```

I also have configured tomcat to use connection pool like this

in conf/context.xml

```
   <Resource url="jdbc:mysql://99.99.99.99:3306/xxx_db?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8&useOldAliasMetadataBehavior=true&autoReconnect=true" 
password="passs123" description="My conection pool" type="javax.sql.DataSource" factory="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory" 
auth="Container" name="jdbc/mysql" defaultAutoCommit="true" removeAbandoned="true" removeAbandonedTimeout="300" 
maxWaitMillis="10000" maxIdle="100" maxTotal="500" driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" username="user1"/>
```

How can I make my application keep working without restarting every day?

Best Regards,

Answer (score 0):

Finally , I found the solution . I have to make a round trip to keep all connection instance active. This can be done via data source configuration in conf/context.xml by adding simple SQL  'select 1' as a test attribute.